# How to add check constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column `BirthDate(date, null)`.

I tried to add check constraint in designer `BirthDate >= 'January 1, 1980'` but got error:

> Unable to add constraint 'CK_MyTable'.
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_MyTable". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb", table "dbo.MyTable", column 'BirthDate'.

When I tried to add the constraint with this T-SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT BirthDate CHECK (BirthDate >= 'January 1, 1900');
```

I got the same error.

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have any existing rows in the table that break that constraint? If so; you have to Update or Delete them and try again.

Comment: @tobypls yeah i have a rows in table. How can i modifity script to add constratint in this case?

Comment: I posted an answer. Try one of the stated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have existing rows in the table that violate the constraint. You can solve this by **either**

1. Delete them

   ```
   DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE BirthDate < '1980-01-01'
   ```

   **OR**
2. Update the existing rows

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET BirthDate = '1980-01-01'/*Your new date*/ 
   WHERE BirthDate < '1980-01-01'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT BirthDate WITH NOCHECK CHECK (BirthDate >= 'January 1, 1900');
```

We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases.

[Unsure of WITH CHECK clause when adding a constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557113/unsure-of-with-check-clause-when-adding-a-constraint)